# Selecting number of adherent by passport type?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE passeport 
(
numero_passeport INTEGER, 
IDadherent INTEGER, 
couleur VARCHAR(6), 
specialite VARCHAR(25), 
date_validation DATE, 
CONSTRAINT pkfh PRIMARY KEY (numero_passeport));

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (1, 001, 'Blanc', null, '1995/02/18');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (2, 002, 'Blanc', null, '2020/02/25');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (3, 003, 'Blanc', null, '2015/04/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (4, 004, 'Blanc', null, '2012/12/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (5, 005, 'Blanc', null, '1996/05/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (6, 006, 'Blanc', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (7, 001, 'Jaune', null, '1998/11/20');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (8, 003, 'Jaune', null, '2018/04/07');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (9, 004, 'Jaune', null, '2013/02/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (10, 005, 'Jaune', null, '2018/05/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (11, 006, 'Jaune', null, '2010/03/08');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (12, 001, 'Orange', null, '2000/03/23');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (13, 003, 'Orange', null, '2019/04/05');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (14, 004, 'Orange', null, '2014/08/06');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (15, 005, 'Orange', null, '2020/01/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (16, 006, 'Orange', null, '2017/01/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (17, 003, 'Vert', null, '2020/06/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (18, 004, 'Vert', null, '2016/01/15');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (19, 006, 'Vert', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (20, 004, 'Bleu', null, '2017/11/14');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (21, 006, 'Bleu', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (21, 004, 'Violet', null, '2018/10/14');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (22, 006, 'Violet', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (23, 004, 'Rouge', 'Performance', '2018/11/18');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (24, 006, 'Rouge', 'Grands espaces', '2011/05/02');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (25, 004, 'Rouge', 'Performance', '2019/12/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (26, 006, 'Rouge', 'Grands espaces', '2011/08/11');


INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (27, 006, 'Noir', 'Bloc', '2012/05/13');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (28, 006, 'Noir', 'voie', '2012/02/06');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (29, 006, 'Noir', 'grande voie', '2015/02/04');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (30, 006, 'Noir', 'compétition bloc', '2018/04/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (31, 006, 'Noir', 'compétition voie', '2019/12/29');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (32, 006, 'Noir','compétition grande voie', '2020/02/18');
```

I'm attempting to make a query to be able to know how many adherents hold each type of passport.

The thing here is that passeport "noir" and "rouge" have various subcategories.

Each time I attempt to run my current query or its variations my program counts the same indvidual holding different subcategories of the passport as different individuals:

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), couleur FROM passeport GROUP BY couleur;
```

Result

```
+----------+---------+
| COUNT(*) | couleur |
+----------+---------+
|        6 | Blanc   |
|        5 | Jaune   |
|        5 | Orange  |
|        3 | Vert    |
|        2 | Bleu    |
|        4 | Rouge   |
|        6 | Noir    |
+----------+---------+
```

I should expect to get 1 individual (IDadherent 006) for the passeport noir.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you want to count *distinct* `IDadherent`s per `couleur`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDadherent) no_adherent, couleur 
FROM passeport 
GROUP BY couleur;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a group on idadherant

Like

```
SELECT COUNT(*),IDadherent, couleur FROM passeport GROUP BY couleur,IDadherent;
```

See

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Adherent 
(
IDadherent INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
nom VARCHAR(30), 
prenom VARCHAR(30)); 
CREATE TABLE passeport 
(
numero_passeport INTEGER, 
IDadherent INTEGER, 
couleur VARCHAR(6), 
specialite VARCHAR(25), 
date_validation DATE, 
CONSTRAINT pkfh PRIMARY KEY (numero_passeport)
  #, 
#CONSTRAINT hfgfg FOREIGN KEY (IDadherent) REFERENCES Adherent(IDadherent)
);

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (1, 001, 'Blanc', null, '1995/02/18');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (2, 002, 'Blanc', null, '2020/02/25');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (3, 003, 'Blanc', null, '2015/04/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (4, 004, 'Blanc', null, '2012/12/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (5, 005, 'Blanc', null, '1996/05/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (6, 006, 'Blanc', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (7, 001, 'Jaune', null, '1998/11/20');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (8, 003, 'Jaune', null, '2018/04/07');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (9, 004, 'Jaune', null, '2013/02/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (10, 005, 'Jaune', null, '2018/05/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (11, 006, 'Jaune', null, '2010/03/08');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (12, 001, 'Orange', null, '2000/03/23');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (13, 003, 'Orange', null, '2019/04/05');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (14, 004, 'Orange', null, '2014/08/06');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (15, 005, 'Orange', null, '2020/01/02');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (16, 006, 'Orange', null, '2017/01/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (17, 003, 'Vert', null, '2020/06/21');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (18, 004, 'Vert', null, '2016/01/15');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (19, 006, 'Vert', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (20, 004, 'Bleu', null, '2017/11/14');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (21, 006, 'Bleu', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (22, 004, 'Violet', null, '2018/10/14');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (23, 006, 'Violet', null, '2009/09/01');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (24, 004, 'Rouge', 'Performance', '2018/11/18');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (25, 006, 'Rouge', 'Grands espaces', '2011/05/02');

INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (26, 004, 'Rouge', 'Performance', '2019/12/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (27, 006, 'Rouge', 'Grands espaces', '2011/08/11');


INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (28, 006, 'Noir', 'Bloc', '2012/05/13');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (29, 006, 'Noir', 'voie', '2012/02/06');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (30, 006, 'Noir', 'grande voie', '2015/02/04');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (31, 006, 'Noir', 'compétition bloc', '2018/04/17');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (32, 006, 'Noir', 'compétition voie', '2019/12/29');
INSERT INTO passeport VALUES (33, 006, 'Noir','compétition grande voie', '2020/02/18');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*), couleur FROM passeport GROUP BY couleur;

| COUNT(*) | couleur |
| -------- | ------- |
| 6        | Blanc   |
| 5        | Jaune   |
| 5        | Orange  |
| 3        | Vert    |
| 2        | Bleu    |
| 2        | Violet  |
| 4        | Rouge   |
| 6        | Noir    |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT COUNT(*),IDadherent, couleur FROM passeport GROUP BY couleur,IDadherent;

| COUNT(*) | IDadherent | couleur |
| -------- | ---------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 2          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 3          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 4          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 5          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 6          | Blanc   |
| 1        | 1          | Jaune   |
| 1        | 3          | Jaune   |
| 1        | 4          | Jaune   |
| 1        | 5          | Jaune   |
| 1        | 6          | Jaune   |
| 1        | 1          | Orange  |
| 1        | 3          | Orange  |
| 1        | 4          | Orange  |
| 1        | 5          | Orange  |
| 1        | 6          | Orange  |
| 1        | 3          | Vert    |
| 1        | 4          | Vert    |
| 1        | 6          | Vert    |
| 1        | 4          | Bleu    |
| 1        | 6          | Bleu    |
| 1        | 4          | Violet  |
| 1        | 6          | Violet  |
| 2        | 4          | Rouge   |
| 2        | 6          | Rouge   |
| 6        | 6          | Noir    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTTpJ9tTudkFrqy1WJghZj/0)